# Issue with CSS min-width and max-width

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list like in the [example demo](https://jsfiddle.net/okbu83mc/)

```css
li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid lightCoral;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 250px;
}
    
li:last-child{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> first item </li>
  <li> second item very long content </li>
  <li> third item </li>
  <li> This is 200px wide</li>
</ul>
```

I want the `li` items to be at least `120px` wide and at most `250px`. If I don't set the width, they automatically set it to `max-width`. But if I set it to `150px` like in the demo, then why doesn't the second one get its maximum allowed width, i.e. `250px` even if its content doesn't fit into a single line?

Is there something I am missing? Can this be done with pure CSS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A div takes by default 100% of its parent's width. So it will take the `max-width`.

To accomplish what you want, float them and clear both sides:

```css
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid lightCoral;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 250px;
}
li:last-child {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item very long content</li>
  <li>third item</li>
  <li>This is 200px wide</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh my god... The day we kill layouts with floats definitively will born a new generation and kittys will be happiest.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour you want is possible if you wrap your `<li>` content inside a `<div>` container. You can then make the `<div>` containers `inline-block` along with `width: auto;` so that they don't conform to having identical lengths and thus you get the bordered boxes around your list elements to be determined by their content as shown in the snippet below.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

li > div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightCoral;
  width: auto;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 250px;
}
    
li:last-child > div{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div> first item </div></li>
  <li><div> second item very long content </div></li>
  <li><div> third item </div></li>
  <li><div> This is 200px wide</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `display: table` property can be used to achieve the effect you want. If you do not set width, the element extends along the length of the content, otherwise the sum of the width of the margin, border, padding, width.

```css
li {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid lightCoral;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
li:last-child{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>second item very long content</li>
  <li>third item</li>
  <li>This is 200px wide</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the code you provided may resolve the issue but please add a brief description as to how this resolves the issue. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [answer].

Comment: The display: table; property is the basis for correct display.

If you do not set width, the element extends along the length of the content, otherwise the sum of the width of the margin, border, padding, width.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I added your text to your answer. You have access to editing your post if you look at the bottom left of it.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you set the `width` to `150px`. If you remove the width attribute or give the `auto` value to it then it will work as expected. Of course, all the items will get the width of the longest of them: [updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/okbu83mc/1/)

```
li {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid lightCoral;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: This sets them all to 250px unless otherwise specified.

Comment: this is not good. I wrote that if I omit `width: 150px` it sets it to `max-width`. It's the same with `width: auto`. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/okbu83mc/3/
If the content is small enough I don't want my list items to have the maximum width.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem, is the normal behaviour of `display: block` elements. If you need that the width be the content's width you can make a `display:inline-block`, and `float:left; clear:both` to avoid the stack problem

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid lightCoral;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 250px;
  clear:both;
  float:left;
}
    
li:last-child{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> first item </li>
  <li> second item very long content </li>
  <li> third item </li>
  <li> This is 200px wide</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated solution [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okbu83mc/5/)

Your CSS

```
li {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   border: 1px solid lightCoral;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 4px 6px;
   margin: 5px;
   min-width: 120px;
   max-width: 250px;
}
```

Your HTML

```
<ul>
   <li> first item </li>
   <li> second item very long content </li>
   <li> third item </li>
   <li> This is 200px wide</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

for your info  `max-width`  is default not set if main `width` is bigger of `max-width` then apply `max-width`.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid lightCoral;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 250px;
}
    
li:last-child{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> first item </li>
  <li> second item very long content </li>
  <li> third item </li>
  <li> This is 200px wide</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set *width* to *auto*:

`width: auto;`