# Applying max-width property for div elements

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to use **max-width** on elements other than images? Or any similar property that helps texts dynamically size itself to the browser window?

Comment: used only <div></div> it's take automaticaly width

Comment: You can use `max-width` in combination with any block element. If you want text to be dynamically resized, use the `vw` or `vh` units instead of pixels.

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584490/issue-with-css-min-width-and-max-width. It's well explained in the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the fiddle.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/00x6fdzd/1/)

`<div></div>` takes the full width.

or

You can provide `max-width` for the `div`

Answer (score 1):

All the elements of display type block automatically get width according to their parent element. However in order to change text size when you increase or decrease the width of your window, you will have to apply media queries. See below code.

```
.x{
  font-size:14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px){
  .x{
    font-size:13px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .x{
    font-size:12px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:440px){
  .x{
    font-size:11px;
  }
}
```

Here `x` is some arbitrary element whose font size you need to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Every block elements support **max-width**. for dynamic fonts sizing things relative to the current viewport size css3 have `vw`, `vh`, and  `vmin`.

you can refer [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/new-css3-relative-font-size/).

I hope this may helps you.